# Is there a way to set SQL connection string automatically?

Tags: c#, sql, connection-string

I am making C# windows form application - is connected to database, so I need connection with it.

The "problem" is that my application should work on any PC.

But, as we know, every PC has different SQL connection string. It would be a little bit unpractical to change connection string in code every time when someone runs application.

So, my question is, is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: "Every PC has different connection string"? Why?

Comment: Are you also installing the database as part of your application? If so you can just use "localhost" to reference the database.

Comment: @Jon Because it has different SQL server name?

Comment: @JKM, yes I am installing database also. I am not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: Usually connectionstrings are stored in the app.config file as a plain text. It is a job of your setup app to change the connectionstring to match the server and other parts of this connectionstring as required by your customer environment

Comment: Your application is connecting to a server/database stored locally on the computer running the application? Use "(local)" as your server name. Also have a look at http://emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2009/05/Using-the-ConnectionStrings-section-of-the-configuration-file.aspx to see how to store your connection string in a config file

Comment: use .\ as server name that points the local instance of sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, your connection strings goes in a [xml .config file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;User Id=USER;Passwor=PASSWORD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And you get them using the [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
```

You will still need to update the .config file on each PC, but not recompile the source.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a example to connect to the same database from all PC

```
    //Geting Connection to database
    static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Northwind; Integrated Security=SSPI");
    }
```